# Get object property using array of object name and proerty name

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I want to find object property dynamically from array that map to property location.

Example

```
 Var objectA = { a:{b:1} };
 Var Names = ['objectA','a','b'];
```

Howa can i get value of `b` by looping over array Names ?

Comment: There's a similar question with the algorithm [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6491621/5743988).

Comment: Why do you feel it's necessary to do this? It seems like an XY Problem to me.

Comment: @zzzBov  i hv a store singelron class, i want other classes to be able to listen for changes that happens on specicifc branch of its data, so i find it best to pass map to prorerty i need to listen to so bthat store emit update event when it changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `objectA` is available in the global scope (`window.objectA`), you could do something like this:

```
names.reduce(function (memo, value) {
    return memo[value]; 
}, window)
```

For any other "non-global" variable, you can create a getter function that takes the variable and the path (an array just like your `names`, but without the first value) as a parameter:

```
function nestedValue(obj, path) {
    return path.reduce(function (memo, value) {
         return memo[value];
    }, obj);
}
```

BTW, please note that `Array.prototype.reduce()` is a ES2015 feature, so if you need to be compatible with older browsers, you would have to use some variation of `for` loop for this task.

You could also check out [lodash.get](https://lodash.com/docs#get) for more sophisticated solution (if you're willing to include it in your project).

Answer (score 1):

You can use eval: `eval(Names.join('.'))`

Can use this with `nodejs` inside a sandbox:

```
const util = require('util');
const vm = require('vm');

const objectA = { a: { b: 1 }};
const Names = ['objectA', 'a', 'b'];

const sandbox = { objectA: objectA, Names: Names };
vm.createContext(sandbox);

for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    vm.runInContext("var result = eval(Names.join('.'))", sandbox);
}
console.log(util.inspect(sandbox));

/* { 
     objectA: { a: { b: 1 } },
     Names: [ 'objectA', 'a', 'b' ],
     result: 1 
   }
*/
```

Comment: Creating a sandbox and using ``eval`` seems like a huge overkill and waste of CPU time.

Answer (score 0):

To do this without eval would require you store `ObjectA` as a property of another object that you could iterate over using the array keys. `eval` will work in this case though:

```js
objectA = { a: { b: 1 }}
names = ['objectA', 'a', 'b']
alert(eval(names.join('.')))
```